# How to override gestures of webview in Android?

Tags: android, events, webview, overriding

I need to override webview gestures ( pinch, swipe, scroll ). The override function should fire scrolableView events. On the other world, I need to fire webview event and scrolableview simultaneously. How can I do :
1- Override webview events ( pinch, swipe, scroll )
2- fire  scrolableview

this is my code, i can see the webview but whenever i touch nothing happen

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {


Context mContext;

public MyWebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext=context;
}


@Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

       new AlertDialog.Builder(null)
    .setTitle("test")
    .setMessage("touched").show();

   return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create your own webview which should extend webview
there you can override ontouchevent method.
here you can do everything

Comment: and how access the srobaleview inside my own class? im very new and dont know how to do

Comment: See the API document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html you can look at the onScrollChanged , onkeydown, onOverScrolled methods. You have to override these methods to do your own operations.